# Möbius Transformations by action of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, mobius-transformation

Consider the group $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ acting on the set $T=\{z\in \mathbb{C}|\text{Im}\hspace{0.1cm}(z)>0\}$. The action is defined by

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\cdot z:= \frac{az+ b}{cz+d}
$$

Lets show that is a group action.

In fact
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \cdot z := \frac{1\cdot z + 0}{0\cdot z+1}=z$$
thus holds the first action condition.

Furthermore, 
$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & b_{1}\\
c_{1} & d_{1}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a_{2} & b_{2}\\
c_{2} & d_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot z=\begin{pmatrix}
(a_{1}a_{2}+b_{1}c_{2}) & (a_{1}b_{2}+b_{1}d_{2})\\
(c_{1}a_{2}+d_{1}c_{2}) & (c_{1}b_{2}+d_{1}d_{2})
\end{pmatrix}\cdot z=\dfrac{(a_{1}a_{2}+b_{1}c_{2})z+ (a_{1}b_{2}+b_{1}d_{2})}{(c_{1}a_{2}+d_{1}c_{2})z+(c_{1}b_{2}+d_{1}d_{2})}
$$
On the other hand, 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & b_{1}\\
c_{1} & d_{1}
\end{pmatrix}\left( \begin{pmatrix}
a_{2} & b_{2}\\
c_{2} & d_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot z\right)=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & b_{1}\\
c_{1} & d_{1}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \frac{a_{2}z+ b_{2}}{c_{2}z+d_{2}}=\frac{a_{1}\frac{a_{2}z+ b_{2}}{c_{2}z+d_{2}}+ b_{1}}{c_{1}\frac{a_{2}z+ b_{2}}{c_{2}z+d_{2}}+d_{1}}=\frac{\frac{a_{1}(a_{2}z+ b_{2})+b_{1}(c_{2}z+d_{2})}{c_{2}z+d_{2}}}{\frac{c_{1}(a_{2}z+ b_{2})+d_{1}(c_{2}z+d_{2})}{c_{2}z+d_{2}}}$$
$$=\frac{a_{1}(a_{2}z+ b_{2})+b_{1}(c_{2}z+d_{2})}{c_{1}(a_{2}z+ b_{2})+d_{1}(c_{2}z+d_{2})}= \dfrac{(a_{1}a_{2}+b_{1}c_{2})z+ (a_{1}b_{2}+b_{1}d_{2})}{(c_{1}a_{2}+d_{1}c_{2})z+(c_{1}b_{2}+d_{1}d_{2})}$$
Thus 
$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & b_{1}\\
c_{1} & d_{1}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
a_{2} & b_{2}\\
c_{2} & d_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot z= \begin{pmatrix}
a_{1} & b_{1}\\
c_{1} & d_{1}
\end{pmatrix}\left( \begin{pmatrix}
a_{2} & b_{2}\\
c_{2} & d_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot z\right)$$
This show the second group action condition.

Therefore that is a group action of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ on the set $T=\{z\in \mathbb{C}|\text{Im}\hspace{0.1cm}(z)>0\}$.

My question is: Do you know about the orbits? Thank you.

Comment: Strictly speaking you've only shown that the action of an element $A \in SL(2, \Bbb R)$ maps an element of say, $T$ to $\Bbb C$, not that it maps an element of $T$ to $T$. It remains to show, then, that $$\operatorname{Im}(A \cdot z) > 0$$ for all $z \in T$, $A \in SL(2, \Bbb R)$.

Comment: NB that $A \cdot z = (-A) \cdot z$ for all $A, z$, so this action actually descends to an action of $PSL(2, \Bbb R)$ on $T$.

Answer (score 5):

It is transitive. So there is only one orbit. Take $z=x+iy$ then we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{y} & x/\sqrt{y}\\
0 & 1/\sqrt{y}
\end{pmatrix}i = z.$$

By the way: The stabilizer of $i$ is
$$\operatorname{SO}_2(\mathbb R) = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
-b & a
\end{pmatrix} : a^2+b^2=1  \right\},$$
so we have
$$ T \cong \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)/\operatorname{SO}_2(\mathbb R).$$